# Spark - Is there a way to cleanup orphaned RDD files and block manager folders (using pyspark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently running/experimenting with Spark in a Windows environment and  have noticed a large number of orphaned blockmgr folders and rdd files.  These are being created when I have insufficient memory to cache a full data set.

I suspect that they are being left behind when processes fail.

At the moment, I am manually deleting them from time to time (when I run out of disk space..... ).  I have also toyed around with a simple file operation script.

I was wondering, is there any pyspark functions or scripts available that would clean these up, or any way to check for them when a process is initiated?

Thanks

Comment: Is this standalone mode? Check some of the cleanup [properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this is standalone mode.  Will check them out

Comment: @cronoik , if you want to expand your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  Gave it a try and seems to do most of what I need (snappy DLL's still hang around, but that seems to be a common complaint).  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @cronoik, this was solved by setting the following properties:

`spark.worker.cleanup.enabled true`

In my instance, using both 'local' and 'standalone' modes on a single node Windows environment, I have set this within spark-defaults.conf file.

Refer to the documentation for more information:  [Spark Standalone Mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)